# Where can I learn about explicit homeomorphisms from $X=\Bbb Z[1/6]^+$ to $Y=\Bbb Z[1/2]\cap(0,1]$ in the 2-adic metric?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, monoid

Where can I learn about explicit homeomorphisms from $X=\Bbb Z[1/6]^+$ to $Y=\Bbb Z[1/2]\cap(0,1]$ in the 2-adic metric?

To be clear, I'm referring to $X$ the products of the positive dyadic and ternary rationals into $Y$ the dyadic rationals in the right-closed unit interval.

Moreover, if possible, a continuous transform from one to the other (NOT necessarily with one as a subspace of the other) whose infinite limit is the homeomorphism. But that would be a luxury and not required to be considered an answer, or a pointer to a suitable source.

I'm a lot more sure now than I was when I wrote the question that I've treated the endpoints $\{0,1\}$ correctly but there's a little scope for error on my part there so modulo a single point is still an answer.

I haven't investigated whether I need group and monoid operations preserved but I assume it unlikely as one is torsion and the other not.

**What I have tried:**

I can make a cover of the dyadic rationals but find it much more tricky to get a cover of the larger set $X$ straight in my mind. I have an inkling what the homeomorphism I have in mind looks like - it writes a 2-adic number from the right in $\Bbb Q_2$ ending with $-1/3$ immediately to the left of the decimal point, and a binary sequence to the right, and then you need to transform that as a whole, either by adding a third or the function $3x+1$ or even $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ to it to get the dyadic rationals in the interval. It's still a work in progress but seeing other, similar examples would help me.

Here's the proposed homeomorphism $X\to Y$:

$T(x)=1+3\sum_{n=0}^\infty (c^n(x)\pmod 2)$

Where $c^n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ composition of $c(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ and $2^{\nu_2(x)}$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $x$.

A couple of things about that which look like they may be significant...

- $(T-1)/3$ is definitely a 2-adic isometry and therefore $T:\text{preimage}(Y)\to Y$ is definitely a homeomorphism
- What I lack is to show that $X$ is the preimage of $Y$.
- The interval of preimage of $Y$ coincides with the interval of $Y$.
- I'm satisfied the preimage of $Y$ has a certain degree of density in $X$
- I can prove that all the integers which are contained in the preimage of $X$ are *final* when we order the numbers by truncating $\frac13(Y-1)$ if odd, and $2Y$ if even

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg although it is next to impossible to convey meaningfully in the medium of a Q&A site and short comments. There is so much in the way of graphing, illustration and explanation which doesn't easily translate into a question here, and it is difficult to convey which parts I am certain of, and where precisely the doubts lie. which need clearing up.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I've edited slightly to eliminate the ambiguities you drew my attention to and I'm also confident I've tidied up the endpoints correctly. If you would please be so good as to indicate whether I've remedied the ambiguities you drew my attention to, I'd be most apprecitive.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If I'm not mistaken, now both your spaces are countable and have no isolated points, which by a remarkable theorem of Sierpinski's implies that they are homeomorphic not only to each other but also to $\mathbb Q$ (in either the archimedean or any of the $p$-adic, and also many other topologies). Cf. https://mathoverflow.net/a/26009/27465. Lest you rejoice about that, I dare say this is rather another setback to your attempts, because it shows there are *many* such homeomorphisms, and it's unlikely they would catch any arithmetic information, let alone Collatz.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg there is a discussion on Xandi Tuni's answer to the question you linked about an explicit homeomorphism, and how if each $x\in \Bbb Q$ had only one continued fraction representation it would yield this. I'm pretty sure your proof of my conjecture that $1-2^{\nu_2(x)}/x$ converges to $0$ on iteration,  yields the unique continued fraction representation they seek in order to get the explicit homeomorphism.